# Is it possible to use "include" and be multi-threaded?

Tags: php

So I am about to write a script that pings multiple devices. I am worried that in the case of network failure that the delay waiting for the packets across 30 devices will cause the script to take 5 min to load.

Is it possible to do:

```
<?php include 'DeviceA.php';?>
<?php include 'DeviceB.php';?>
<?php include 'DeviceC.php';?>
```

But have them be threaded so that they all run simultaneously and output when ready?

Comment: I guess yes. PHP has a thread safe option as well.

Comment: I mean does it just thread by default? or does it need something else? Am i missing something?